# xelatex,Texlive 2020, MacPro Monterey 12.5 "unable to load picture" with \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics{/usr/hr/Images/Retour.jpg}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have the answer: image is not found.

Comment: None of us have the file in question, so none of us can test your code. Are you sure the file exists (keeping in mind that file names are case sensitive)? Does it work if you change `/usr/hr/Images/Retour.jpg` to `example-image-a`?

Comment: This is a low level error message by XeTeX, issued when the file is not a valid picture file. Check it.

Comment: Where does `/usr/hr` come from? Do you hav e read permissions there? In recent versions of macOS you can’t add directories to `/usr`.